# How do i send BasicAuth with HttpClient.get_async in ruby?

Tags: ruby, httpclient

I've tried the following but the BASIC_AUTHENTICATION flag does not seem to be getting set on the other end, and am getting an '401 Unauthorized' error.

```
client = HTTPClient.new
client.set_auth(nil, "user", "secret")
client.get_async(full_url, {:id => hash[:id]}, {username: "user", password: "secret"})

# HOWEVER THIS WORKS, non-async
# client.get(full_url, {:id => hash[:id]}, {username: "user", password: "secret"})
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just send it in as a header:

```
client    = HTTPClient.new
auth      = Base64.strict_encode64("user:secret")
client.get_async(full_url, {:id => hash[:id]}, {'Authorization' => auth})
```